# Adding an id to a g:link in Grails

Tags: grails, gsp

Is there anyway to add an *id* to a `<g:link>` tag?

In my .gsp file, I have the following code:

```
<g:link controller="application" action="index" id="my_id">My Link</g:link>
```

Grails produces the following HTML:

```
<a href="application/index">My Link</a>
```

According to the [grails documentation](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Tags/link.html), *id* is a valid attribute for `<g:link>`. So why is my *id* gone? Is there any workaround to tell grails to keep the *id* there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Use `elementId` instead of `id`. Like this:

`<g:link controller="application" action="index" elementId="my_id">My Link</g:link>`

You can read more about the attributes for the `link` tag in the [documentation](https://gsp.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/link.html).